# QT Creator c++ writing Kakuro puzzle and unsure of what widget to use

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm using QT creator and have all my methods etc designed and trying to design a UI and I'm not sure what widget I should be using to reference my puzzle layout.

I've been reading over the documentation for a while and I still am nowhere closer to finding a solution to what I should be using to display my values. I know what I should like but all I seem to find information on is various layouts of entry boxes that are in no way linked. I have no problem with coding it myself to communicate with my classes if I just knew what to use to start off with.

I need something that can help me create a layout that has up to two numbers with positions specific to the type of hint it is with a slash between the hints, black blocks that are neither hints nor stored values and squares that have values that can take up the whole square.

Layout is something similar to http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/kakuro/
I wish I knew what to pick >.<

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use `QGraphicsView` and handle the drawing myself.

It can draw rectangles, triangles, circles and text without much effort, and that's pretty much everything you need as far as I can see. You just need to add the objects to a `QGraphicsScene` and you get them on the screen. You can also interact with the objects (you can find which object you're pointing at etc.)

Comment: That does look like it would work.  I'll start looking at it and seeing what I can do to implement it. Thanks. I guess I missed it because I kept looking at auto-generated options.